# How to find out which program is being run for command prompt (WINDOWS)?

Tags: windows, command-prompt

When using Windows command prompt I found a number of linux commands working. e.g. `ls`.

How can I find out the program being run from only the command name?

Comment: use `where ls`. replace `ls` with a command.

Comment: can you write your comment as an answer please. Thanks!!! You have no idea how long i have been searching for this. I just didn't know what to search for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Windows Command Prompt (cmd.exe), you can use the `where` command. It will search your path for which executable to run. It may list more than one entry, but the first one is the one that gets used.